# How do I post Python generated GFS plots on my website?

Tags: python, html, matplotlib, pythonanywhere

I have a Python script that ingests GFS model data and plots it using matplotlib. How do I get those exact plots to display on a website? I am currently using PythonAnywhere to build my webpage.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Python Anywhere has a variety of options for how you can host your website/web application--so the details of how to do this will depend on how you are hosting your site.

One option is Flask, and I'll just point you to Matplotlib's [example](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/user_interfaces/web_application_server_sgskip.html) on embedding Matplotlib within Flask.

Another option is to generate the plots statically somewhere, and then upload them into your static website content. I'm not sure how exactly one one would go about that with Python Anywhere.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response. I will check this out and follow up if I have any more questions. Thank you!